# What are the disadvantages of re-using the same IP scope in multiple subnets?

Tags: networking, subnet

We're designing a somewhat large system that we're not really qualified to design. It will be something like a campus: one main, large network, with about 20 sub-networks that are like departments with a few subnets for different labs or subsystems that need to be on their own VLANS.

The debate is, should we try to get each department it's own IP space, or use the same space for each department and hide behind NAT. Either way there will be decent, layer 3 switches for the gateway of each department.

The argument for using the same scope over and over is that it will be easier to configure these cookie-cutter subsystems the same for each department. There are a lot of non-pc, non-network-device devices in the systems that need to be manually configured with static IPs. The plan for administering these devices remotely is to open a couple ports in the NAT to vnc/remote-desktop to a PC inside. Then use the applications installed on that PC and web-guis to manage the devices. I think the NAT table will just grow and grow, but at least the config will be able to be easily duplicated to all the routers.

I feel like you lose a lot of advanced networking features by doing it that way. Off the top of my head: central dns and dhcp services, deploying OS images over the network to crashed machines, deploying configuration and media...

What else?

Feel free to edit my title and post to make more sense. Should I make a drawing?

Comment: "We're designing a somewhat large system that we're not really qualified to design." Oh dear. Hire someone that knows what they're doing. Seriously. This is not complex stuff, but with your general lack of experience, you're going to shoot yourselves in the foot dozens of times.

Comment: Also: **do not** duplicate subnets, and **do not** NAT (except at your internet egress point perhaps). You have millions of IP addresses in the RFC1918 space(s) available to you. There's no good reason to duplicate.

Comment: What kind of `non-network-device` needs an IP address...  If there is no network, how is there IP?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because solving this problem the right way requires that the OP hire a network engineer.

Comment: comment: this is a legit question with no duplicates that I can find.

Comment: There's no debate here: Trying to give everyone the same private IP space and NAT between them is patently absurd. Nobody will be able to talk to each other, and that includes the administrators who have to manage this nightmare!

Comment: @tladuke - agreed - it's a legit question. Unfortunately, we're bound by making professional recommendations, and in your case the recommendation is to hire someone to help you out. You'll have a much better end result, and you'll learn a **ton** through the process.

Comment: @tladuke - the problem is 2 fold with your question. 1) you need a minimal understanding of network design, which SF isn't going to give you a walkthrough on why this idea is bad.  2) It's too broad.  The whole `if you can imagine a book being the answer` is spot on for designing a network.  A consultant needs to work with you, find out the requirements, develop a solution, tweak it a few times, etc.  This isn't something that is a straight Q&A for SF.

Comment: Well, for the record, I am the one trying to talk everybody out of it, and I have multiple times suggested maybe talk to an actual network engineer. Thanks for the few comments and answers that made it through.

Comment: @tladuke  Maybe update the resume, so you can jump ship if/when it get unbearably bad... and whatever you do, resist the temptation to say "I told you so" when it blows up in their faces.  It's never as satisfying as you think it would be.

Answer (score 3):

The main curse of reused subnets is also its blessing: the subnets will not have any way to route between them, so they will never be able to talk to each other.  This is bad if you want  to interconnect them, but good if you want to force them to be isolated.

You can still support networks services outside the NAT layers - but not behind the NAT unless you forward ports.

I for one would not use such a system; I would instead use routers between the distinct broadcast domains to interconnect the various domains.  On those routers I would be able to add any firewaling I might want.